What is the produced Drag by a Jet Engine on an airliner?
Are there certain estimation formulas to calculate the drag created by a Jet engine mounted above the fuselage, as shown?
Digital DATCOM seems not to estimate it.


There's formulae for everything. Now how to calculate the drag caused by something with the drag coefficient of that engine will require all the measurements and then you can calculate it. For this exact thing, maybe CFD is better
